# Is there a better way to set an alarm instead of comparing time using timers?

Tags: vb.net, time, alarm

The header pretty much says it all. I've been using timer components set to half a second ticks and comparing tables of alarm details and I was wondering if there was something better I just haven't seen.

'''

```
    For Each r As DataRow In AlarmsFromDataBase.Rows
        Dim CurrentTime As DateTime = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second)

        If (DateTime.Compare(r("DateTimeAlarms"), CurrentTime) = 0) And r("AlarmHandled") <> True Then
            r("AlarmHandled") = True
            MsgBox("match found")
        End If
    Next
```

'''

This works of course, but is there a more efficient or elegant way of doing this?

Comment: *"The header pretty much says it all"*. That is never the case.

Comment: Think about how an alarm clock works.  You specify the alarm to go off at the time you want, right?  Do that with a `Timer`.  Calculate the amount of time until you want the alarm to go off and set that as `Interval` of the `Timer`.  When the `Tick` event is raised, you know it's time, so no comparison is necessary.  The `Interval` is milliseconds and type `Integer`, so can support up to about 24 days.

Comment: If you have multiple alarms, you just set the `Interval` for the first one.  When it goes off, you set it for the next one, etc.